# Eliminating code duplication when querying multiple tables with the same schema's

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've inherited some code which uses multiple tables to store the same information depending on how old it is (one for the current day, the last month, etc.).

Currently most of the code is duplicated for every condition, and I'd like to try and eliminate the majority of the duplication in the stored procedures.  Right now re-architecting the design is not an option as there are a number of applications that depend on the current design that I have no control over.

One option I've tried so far is loading the needed data into a temp table which I found to have a rather large performance hit.  I've also tried using a cte structured like this:

```
;WITH cte_table(...) 
AS 
(
  SELECT ...
  FROM a
  WHERE @queried_date = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())

  UNION ALL

  SELECT ...
  FROM b
  WHERE @queried_date BETWEEN --some range
)
```

This works and the performance isn't terrible, but it's not very nice looking.

Could anyone offer a better alternative?

Comment: "This works and the performance isn't terrible" - not sure there is a question there...

Comment: So what are you exactly looking for? And you may share what code is exactly duplicated? Is it the code to access different tables (CRUD operations) for the different dates of the data?

Comment: It probably looks worse to a procedural coder. I hope you have a really solid unit-testing strategy to prove you end up with identical results and the same or better performance, under load.

Comment: If you're going to keep writing that CTE and the conditions don't vary, make it a view, but otherwise, I also don't see the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Just use `UNION`, not `UNION ALL`.  The [UNION operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) removes duplicates in that case.  `UNION ALL` preserves dupes.
2. Using the CTE, the `SELECT` clause on the outside / end can have a `DISTICT` operator to bring back unique rows.  Of course, not sure why you'd be using a CTE in this scenario since UNION should work just fine.  (In fact, I believe SQL will optimize the query to the same plan structure either way...)

Any way you slice it, if you have duplicate data, either you have to do something like the above, or you have to make explicit clauses that remove dupe cases, using things like #temp tables or WHERE ... NOT IN ().

Comment: As I read it, he's concerned about code duplication, not data duplication. As I read it, the data in each table *is* distinct, so these suggestions will just add overhead.

Comment: Yeah - re-read that.  I suppose creating UNIONed views to abstract the multiple tables would simplify the SQL coding.  Might get tricky with Create, Update, Delete [solvable "cleanly"], but in effect you're creating a Partitioned View (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933141(v=sql.80).aspx).